# About "this" usage

Tags: java, this

I am studying `Java` language.

When I studied about keyword `this`, I wonder if I can allocate other object to `this`.

for example, If I make a method that its parameter is an object, Can I make a current object refer a parameter object using `this` keyword?

Comment: this keyword is meant to use with the calling object only.

Comment: The this keyword is always a shortcut reference to the current object. You can refer to variables or methods in the current object via this also e.g. `this.username`, or `this.getPassword()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you can't. In a sense `this` is implicitly `final`: *i.e.* it cannot be changed to refer to a different object.

Also, you can't deviate from the language's definition of `this`. It's a *keyword* so therefore cannot be used for anything else.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot, this is a Java Keyword.

Look at the [oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) for all keywords.

> Here is a list of keywords in the Java programming language. You cannot use any of the following as identifiers in your programs. The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used. true, false, and null might seem like keywords, but they are actually literals; you cannot use them as identifiers in your programs.

Comment: Nicked the bulk of this answer to complete mine, better upvote to clear my battered conscience.

Answer (score 3):

The `this` keyword in Java is much like the `I` word in english. It is obviously insane to image that you can point `this` at a different object in the same way you cannot make "*I am wearing a blue shirt*" to imply the colour of anyones shirt than your own.